Use Vuelidate with i18n (English/Persian)
According to this part of vuelidate documentation https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/advanced_usage.html#i18n-support, I have some issues with using vuelidate with vue-i18n and also there is a problem with Persian characters when using rules, It cannot recognize Persian letters and validate them.
I really need help using vuelidate to validate fields in Persian(Farsi) and English.
version:
"@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.3",
"@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.4",
"vue-i18n": "^9.11.0"
Thank a lot you for your help
here is my i18n.js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from '@/locales/en.json'
import fa from '@/locales/fa.json'

function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = [{ en: en }, { fa: fa }]
  const messages = {}
  locales.forEach((lang) => {
    const key = Object.keys(lang)
    messages[key] = lang[key]
  })
  return messages
}

export default createI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'fa',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})

and here is my validation.js
it doesn't provide t, t.bind and i18n
import * as validators from '@vuelidate/validators'
import { i18n } from "@/i18n"

const { createI18nMessage } = validators

const withI18nMessage = createI18nMessage({ t: i18n.global.t.bind(i18n) })

export const required = withI18nMessage(validators.required)

export const minLength = withI18nMessage(validators.minLength, { withArguments: true })
export const maxLength = withI18nMessage(validators.maxLength(10))```


The question lacks clear problem statement. What exactly is the problem? You describe it like it's something that goes without saying but it's not. " some issues" - which exactly? "It cannot recognize Persian letters and validate them" - please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , a locale should make no difference for this kind of rules (minLength, etc)

thanks for reply @Estus Flask actually the code is clear and I said that this code according to vuelidate documentation doesn't work, any ideas to work?

Are there any error logs? If you are saying that its behavior does not meet expectations, please describe its behavior and your expectations. This helps to effectively troubleshoot.

@m.ma See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You need to provide a way to reproduce, the problem is specific to your case, and you didn't explain it enough. " it doesn't provide t, t.bind and i18n" - what does this mean? Are they undefined or else?
